# Can a gradient descent method converge to to nonstrict local maxima?

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

In $\star$, the authors prove that 'almost always' gradient method converges to a local minimum provided the objective function has strict saddle properties. Nesterov, in his book, has given an example proving that gradient descent methods can converge to a saddle point. I was wandering for an example of the objective function for which the steepest descent method converges to a nonstrict local maximum. Does there exist one?

---

<sub>$\star $Jason D. Lee, Max Simchowitz, Michael I. Jordan, Benjamin Recht, [Gradient descent converges to minimizers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.04915), 2016.</sub>

Comment: Assume that the SD method does not start from a point of strict maximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a point have derivative zero, the steepest descent converges to that point with a constant sequence, if it starts at that stationary point.

---

**Counterexample required in the comment section**:

---

Consider the function $x \mapsto (\cos((\cos(x))^2_{+})-1)x$, with $t_{+} = t, $ if $t \geq 0$, and $t_{+}=0$, if $t< 0.$ This function is constant in a countable quantity of closed intervals. The quantity of strict maximum is countable and are in between these disjoint intervals in the negative axis. Now, it's not hard to find a negative staring point, say $x_0$, close to a strict local maximum such that in the next step it ends in one of that intervals where the function is constant.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is true. Thank you for the answer. However, I was actually wandering for an example when the SD method does not start from the initial point. Can you help me out?

Comment: It's possible, but it's just hard to construct such a problem. I was trying, and the problem is just to find an unbounded function with several nonstrict local maximums, but it seems hard.

Comment: Yes, I also sense so but unable to construct. If you find it, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added your counterexample.

Comment: In the example, do you want to mean $x \mapsto (\cos ((\cos (x)_+)^2 -1)x$?

Comment: Thank you so much, Prado

Comment: Not exacly, I mean $x \mapsto (\cos(\cos(x)^2_{+})-1)x$. I will edit. Both formulations are equivalent, but with the cosine function is simpler. Here in this problem, all points in the negative axis that are nonstrict local maximum are local minimum, but not otherwise. The nonstrict  local maximum looks like local minimum, and they are as well.